# Spotify Implicit Grant won't work on node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, spotify

I am trying to make the codes you see here: 
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/amusing-swallow?path=index.html:7:68

executable on my node js application. Please note that the codes on that link is working.

What I did is that I set up an environment like this:

```
root folder
  --public
     --index.html
  --script.js
  --app.js
  --package.json
```

And then I copied the html code to my index.html file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Spotify Implicit Grant Template</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://sp-bootstrap.global.ssl.fastly.net/8.0.0/sp-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body class="container">
  <h1 class="text-salmon">Spotify Implicit Grant Template</h1>
  <h3>This app uses the implicit grant authorization flow to authenticate users and get user data.</h3>
  <p>
    Here are your top artists on Spotify:
    <ol id="top-artists"></ol>
  </p>
  <script src="../script.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Nothing special and then I made the script.js a self invoking function like this:

```
(function() {
  // Get the hash of the url
  const hash = window.location.hash
    .substring(1)
    .split("&")
    .reduce(function(initial, item) {
      if (item) {
        var parts = item.split("=");
        initial[parts[0]] = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);
      }
      return initial;
    }, {});
  window.location.hash = "";

  // Set token
  let _token = hash.access_token;

  const authEndpoint = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize";

  // Replace with your app's client ID, redirect URI and desired scopes
  const clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  const redirectUri = "http://localhost:8888/callback/";
  const scopes = ["user-top-read"];

  // If there is no token, redirect to Spotify authorization
  if (!_token) {
    window.location = `${authEndpoint}?client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&scope=${scopes.join(
      "%20"
    )}&response_type=token&show_dialog=true`;
  }

  // Make a call using the token
  $.ajax({
    url:
      "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=tania+bowra&offset=0&limit=20&type=artist",
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + _token);
    },
    success: function(data) {
      // Do something with the returned data
      data.items.map(function(artist) {
        let item = $("<li>" + artist.name + "</li>");
        item.appendTo($("#top-artists"));
      });
    }
  });
})();
```

And then finally on my app.js for express:

```
var express = require("express"); // Express web server framework
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
console.log("Listening on host 8888......");
app.listen(8888);
```

So I tried to run this and whenever I visit the localhost:8888, I keep on getting these:

```
GET http://localhost:8888/script.js 404 (Not Found)

Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8888/script.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

I am not sure why. But I just copied the same exact code and just put my credentials there but it won't still work. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to replace `__dirname + "/public"` to `path.join(__dirname, "/public")`

Comment: @TheReason I did and the outcome is the same. I require path too.

Comment: Your server servers the public folder, you ask for the `script.js` file, so your server search for it inside the public folder ... but it is not there, so the server returns a 404 code error. Move the `script.js` inside the public folder and fix the path inside your html. Since the root folder of your webservice is the public folder the browser has no access the the parent folders.